# D3.js Strings From Data in Axis TickValues

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to show names of the people in my D3js graph y-axis. The y-axis built up by peopleid attribute and here is my data value and usage:

```
{"people": "phileas fogg", "peopleid": 0,"id": 1,"locations": "burlington gardens"}

var yValue = function(d) { return d["peopleid"];},
    yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    yMap = function(d) {return yScale(yValue(d));}, 
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left").tickValues(d3.range(0, width, 1))
```

I searched about the issue but most of the cases are about time & date and I couldn't find one like in my case.

Comment: If you want to show the names of peoples, then you need to use ordinal scale. [**`Link`**](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales) for it.

Comment: Isn't there a way to show string ticks on linear view? I don't want to use ordinal scale.

Comment: If you have a way of mapping your id values to your string values, you can do it with a tick formatting function.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21127647/3128209); the only difference is that you'll need to dynamically create the label key:value object from your data.  But you'll still have problems if the tick values end up at non-integer numbers that don't match an id value.  This is really what ordinal scales are intended for...